# How do I do geospatial queries using IBM Databases for MongoDB using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ibm-cloud, geospatial

I have collection GeoJSON locations that represent US states. How can I find which states intersect a hypothetical storm which is also a GeoJSON object? Can MongoDB perform this query?

Answer (score 3):

First we need a MongoDB collection that contains the US states as GeoJSON e..g https://github.com/glynnbird/usstatesgeojson. We can import the data into a new MongoDB database/collection using a Node.js script:

```js
// connection credentials
const MONGO_DB = process.env.MONGO_DB
const MONGO_COLLECTION = process.env.MONGO_COLLECTION
const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI
const MONGO_CERT_FILE = process.env.MONGO_CERT_FILE
if (!MONGO_DB || !MONGO_COLLECTION || !MONGO_URI || !MONGO_CERT_FILE) {
  console.error('Missing MONGO configuration')
  process.exit(1)
}

// constants
const DATA_DIR = './locations'

// import dependencies
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const mongodb = require('mongodb')

const main = async () => {
  // connect to MongoDB
  const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient
  const opts = {
    tls: true,
    tlsCAFile: MONGO_CERT_FILE,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }
  const mongoClient = new MongoClient(MONGO_URI, opts)
  await mongoClient.connect()


  // create db and collection
  const db = await mongoClient.db(MONGO_DB)
  const collection = db.collection(MONGO_COLLECTION)

  // get a list of data files to import
  const files = fs.readdirSync(DATA_DIR)
  for(const f of files) {
    const contents = fs.readFileSync(path.join(DATA_DIR, f), { encoding: 'utf8' })
    const obj = JSON.parse(contents)
    await collection.insertOne(obj)
    console.log('Inserted', obj._id)
  }

  // create geospatial index
  await collection.createIndex( { geometry: "2dsphere" } )
  console.log('created geospatial index')
  
  // exit
  process.exit()
}

main()
```

This script expects your MongoDB service's credentials to be in environment variables:

- `MONGO_DB` - the database name
- `MONGO_COLLECTION` - collection name
- `MONGO_URI` - the URL
- `MONGO_CERT_FILE` - the path of the CA certificate

> You can obtain your service's URL and certificate from the [IBM Cloud dashboard](https://cloud.ibm.com/resources).

The script looks for the GeoJSON files in a directory called "locations" and inserts them into a database/collection specified by the environment variables.

It also instructs MongoDB to create a geospatial index on the data's "geometry" attribute:

```js
await collection.createIndex( { geometry: "2dsphere" } )
```

This says "create a '2dsphere' index on the data stored in the 'geometry' attribute".

We are now ready to query the collection.

We need candidate weather event, expressed as GeoJSON e.g.

[image: fictional weather event]

> Notice that the storm overlaps four US states.

The query code is as follows and uses the same environment variables as the first script:

```js
// connection credentials
const MONGO_DB = process.env.MONGO_DB
const MONGO_COLLECTION = process.env.MONGO_COLLECTION
const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI
const MONGO_CERT_FILE = process.env.MONGO_CERT_FILE
if (!MONGO_DB || !MONGO_COLLECTION || !MONGO_URI || !MONGO_CERT_FILE) {
  console.error('Missing MONGO configuration')
  process.exit(1)
}

// import dependencies
const fs = require('fs')
const mongodb = require('mongodb')

const main = async () => {
  // connect to MongoDB
  const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient
  const opts = {
    tls: true,
    tlsCAFile: MONGO_CERT_FILE,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }
  const mongoClient = new MongoClient(MONGO_URI, opts)
  await mongoClient.connect()

  // configure db and collection
  const db = await mongoClient.db(MONGO_DB)
  const collection = db.collection(MONGO_COLLECTION)
  
  // this is our incoming weather event
  const data = fs.readFileSync('./storm.geojson', { encoding: 'utf8' })
  const storm = JSON.parse(data)

  // find which locations are affected by the storm
  const results = await collection.find({
    geometry: {
      '$geoIntersects' : {
        '$geometry': {
          type: storm.geometry.type,
          coordinates: storm.geometry.coordinates
        }
      }
    }
  }).toArray()
  
  // output the list of location ids
  console.log(results.map((r) => { return r._id }))

  // die
  process.exit()

}

main()
```

It loads the candidate weather event from `storm.json`:

```
{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[-77.00416876685775,34.60867695038871],[-78.93776251685789,35.1134983061437],[-80.99220587623299,35.158420777504745],[-83.65089728248286,34.671948926428996],[-83.85963751685802,33.891272054223364],[-83.84865118873311,32.010746736868654],[-83.31032111060784,31.309406168163207],[-82.45338751685738,30.6311690732732],[-80.15724493873236,30.385070283872437],[-79.03663946998299,30.49873173190622],[-77.44362189185789,31.674764007288985],[-76.56471564185757,33.029728245050364],[-76.64161993873286,33.69040245253204],[-77.00416876685775,34.60867695038871]]],"type":"Polygon"}}
```

then performs a geospatial query using MongoDB:

```js
  const results = await collection.find({
    geometry: {
      '$geoIntersects' : {
        '$geometry': {
          type: storm.geometry.type,
          coordinates: storm.geometry.coordinates
        }
      }
    }
  }).toArray()
```

This translates to "find documents whose 'geometry' field intersects the geometry of the storm".

The script outputs four results:

```
[ 'south carolina', 'north carolina', 'georgia', 'florida' ]
```